# DIV background not stretching properly

Tags: css, html, stretch

I have the following HTML code:

```
<style>
body {
background:#547c15;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#inner {
margin:0 auto;
width:1298px;
}
#outer {
background:#000;
}
</style>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I am viewing this on a widescreen monitor, everything is fine. But when I am viewing this on a older CRT monitor in a 800X600 resolution, the outer div is NOT fully stretched over the inner div. There is a scroll on the bottom (due to the inner div being 1298px) but the outer div is stretched only to 800px (see image below).

[image: Problem with DIV stretch]

Can someone please help me out with this? I want the outer div to always be 100% width (i.e. the background color/image should always stretch out completely even when there is a horizontal scrollbar).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Give it `min-width: 1298px` too?

Comment: #rohan, did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing the exact same behavior and can't explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Give the outer div `width:100%;` to make it resize to contain the inner contents, I think it will work, if in case it doesn't work than use `min-width:1298px;`

Answer (score 0):

In your #outer add this:

```
    float:left; width:100%;
```

Comment: Get rid if `width: 100%` and this will work. The `float` forces the div to wrap to the width of the children, but then `width: 100%` negates this effect and makes it the width of the browser window and returns to the original problem