# Stretch parent node to its content width

Tags: html, css, dom, width

```
<div style='width:100%;background-color:green;padding:10px;'>
  <div style='width: 5000px;background-color:red; padding:5px;'>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8xqwW/2/

Outer div is fixed at 100% of window, while inner one is rendered at full width.

Is there any way to make outer div to stretch to the inner one's width (if it is big) while remaining at at least 100% of the window (if inner div is small)?

I cannot use **overflow-x:scroll** - only window scroll is allowed. Also **min-width:100%** didn't solve my problem.

If no solution exists I can use JS resize event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `display:table` for outer div

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as an answer. What benefits would display: table have on the outer div if the display mode of the child hasn't changed?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, could you please rephrase you question? I dont understand how it is related to the initial one

Comment: It works. Checked in IE 7, 8 and latest Firefox and Chrome. Thank you. (Also, I suspect that using table instead of outer div will work too)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks this doesn't explain the behavior though. Why does it do that? There's another question on Stack with similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275222/div-background-not-stretching-properly. I'm having the same problem and whilst I don't mind doing as you suggested, it would be nice to know why this is happening