# Outer DIV not stretching full WIDTH of screen although inner DIV does

Tags: html, css

There are similar questions on stack with some suggested answers (some don't work in IE7 like settings display:table), others don't have answers so I'm hoping someone can explain **why browsers render the following HTML as they do and what the proper approach is**.

You can see the working sample at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wDeCg/1/

The HTML:

```
<div class="bottom-background-image">
    <div class="site-width">asdfasdfasdf</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:beige;
    margin: 0;
}
.bottom-background-image {
    background-color:green;
}
.site-width {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Here's the unwanted result, which is that the parent DIV with a green background doesn't stretch the full width as expected. It seems to only take up the available screen width. Since the inner DIV is setting the width surely the outer DIV with no explicit width set should adopt the inner DIVs width? :

[image]

Similar questions:

[DIV background not stretching properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275222/div-background-not-stretching-properly)

[Stretch parent node to its content width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218445/stretch-parent-node-to-its-content-width)

Comment: No reference, so only comment: `display:block` generally stretch only as wide as its parent, so in this case, the inner DIV is _overflow_ ing.

Comment: @Passerby, if you look at the code though it doesn't make any sense. How do you see the inner DIV is overflowing?

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` to outer DIV.

Comment: If you make outer DIV `display:inline-block`, it will stretch. The default behavior of block element is to be as wide as its parent. And by default BODY is only as wide as the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Define** your `css` in you `body` `min-width:1024px;`

```
body{min-width: 1024px;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/wDeCg/2/)**

Comment: Agreed. It's good practice to ensure your `<body>` doesn't shrink thinner than your sites fixed/min width

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Azad this does actually solve it. It doesn't make sense though WHY this works the way it does. Surely the other DIV's width (bottom-background-image) should be determined by the inner DIV's width. And, only in the case where the inner DIV's width is wider than the browsers viewport? 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/wDeCg/3/

```
.bottom-background-image {
    background-color:green;
    min-width:1024px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    background-color:beige;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
}
.bottom-background-image {
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
}
.site-width {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: this creates a horizontal scroll bar just bellow the green area, it shouldn't be doing that. There's no need for that scroll since the browser window will do the scrolling?